# Is it possible to change the font/style/color of inline hints?

Tags: netbeans

I did not know it was a thing, and after formatting and installing netbeans 17 it was turned on by default. It is cool and all, and id like to use it, but i cant find any options for it besides on/off. I think it is half my font size (judging by how it changes if i change the "default" font size), so its a barely readable 6.5 points on a 1080p monitor. Id like to change it to the same size, and make it italics. If it is not possible then i will just keep not using it like always, no loss.

Comment: You can't independently configure the font size for hints in NetBeans. But I think it's indirectly tied to the font size used by the NetBeans IDE, and you can easily increase that. However, you will probably find that counterproductive, because although the font size for hints will be larger, everything else in the IDE (e.g. menu entries, the projects tab, error messages) will also be larger, and probably much larger than you want. Anyway, it is trivial to try it: just include the **fontsize** parameter when starting NetBeans. For example: `C:\NetBeans17\bin\netbeans64.exe --fontsize 36`